# activity stack corrupted after update?

Tags: android

Initial Activity (A) launches activity (B).  When the user is on (B), presses home, and then returns to the app, (B) is shown again.  If you update the app (I am updating from an email as it is not published yet) and launch it from the update screen, it will no longer remember to return to (B).  It just restarts activity (A).

If you exit the app by pressing the back button, then from there on it continues to work correctly.

I see something like this described here: [Activity history stack wrong upon first install on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845460/758074).  Is this a known Android bug?  I am running honeycomb and ICS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is the same answer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3890397/758074

From what I can tell, the issue is that when you launch an app from the android installer it launches an instance of Activity (A) into the existing Task.  As described in the answer link above, the bug is described

here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373
and here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658

This code in Activity (A) onCreate() did workaround the issue.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isTaskRoot()) 
    {
        Log.d("SplashActivity", "Splash is not Task Root, finish()");
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```