# Fail to resume the activity stack during 1st launching after installation

Tags: android

Our application has a splash activity (main activity for launcher) and many other activities. In most cases, when the user switches the application into background and resumes it from launcher, the old activity stack is resumed and top activity in that stack is shown as expected.

However, when the apk is just installed on the phone, or a new apk (with higher version) of the same application is installed, its behavior is strange. When the application is switched to background and resumed from launcher, the previous activity stack is not resumed and the splash activity is always shown. If we resume the application from recent applications list, the activity stack is resumed as expected. Only after killing the task from recent applications list, everything becomes normal again. The previous activity stack will always be resumed correctly until it is replaced by another apk installation again.

My Android version is 4.1.2 and I am using its default launcher.

Following is configuration of the splash activity.

```
<activity android:name=".welcome.activity.SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Who has any idea about the strange behavior? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "whenever a new apk of the same application is installed" - wait, so on a fresh phone, everything works fine. Once you install a new version (>version number), it screws up?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't say that precisely. I have just tested that by removing the application and installing the apk again, the strange behavior also happens. Again, once after killing that in the recent applications list, everything becomes OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found this is an issue of Android system. It has already been discussed in [Activity history stack wrong upon first install on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845460/activity-history-stack-wrong-upon-first-install-on-device).

I have adopted a workaround stated in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373#c40 and it works well, i.e. adding the following code in SplashActivity.onCreate():

```
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really able to tell what's going on without knowing more about your app. I would look into:

- The `launchMode` manifest element: [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)
- Check your activities are not being destroyed and recreated by the system: [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)
- If you are doing anything with fragments and if these are maintaining state correctly

Sorry, bit of a guess!

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to show your Splash Activity once, you can use finish() after you launched the Main Activity, that should solve your problem.

Comment: I had already invoked finish() in splash activity after launching the main activity.