# Pause and resume not working correctly

Tags: android, onresume, onpause

In my app when app start for the first time and I press Home button from device. And then start it again its start from beginning. After that each time I start it and press Home key and then start it again its start from same point where I leave it. How to solve this first time run error?

Code-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);
        textView1 = (TextViewEx) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setText("Text", true);
        textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }

    public void onBackPressed()  
    {    
        intent = new Intent(History.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
            finish(); 
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        objIntent = new Intent(History.this, PlayAudio.class);
        stopService(objIntent);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        objIntent = new Intent(History.this, PlayAudio.class);
            startService(objIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }    
}
```

Comment: So its not behaving properly *only* the first time you press home button?

Comment: you need to save the state and data  in shared preference and each time start load previous state

Comment: This is a known issue in android... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373#c40 and see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000097/fail-to-resume-the-activity-stack-during-1st-launching-after-installation and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time

Comment: @Gautham yes in first time.

Comment: @GopalRao can you help me on this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569347/navigating-up-and-overflow-icon-in-action-bar

Comment: @JohnR have you solved that Overflow menu problem?

Comment: @GopalRao no please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569347/overflow-icon-is-not-shown

Comment: @GopalRao please post your answer including links you send me for this question. This problem solved.

Comment: @JohnR Glad to help you and let the comment to be a comment. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
private boolean paused = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history);
    textView1 = (TextViewEx) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setText("Text", true);
    textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}

...

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    paused = true;
}

@Override 
public void onResume()
{
    // On resume loads every times when activity starts after onCreate
    super.onResume();
    if(paused){
        objIntent = new Intent(History.this, PlayAudio.class);
        startService(objIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to restart the activity every time it launches?

Comment: Put finish(); in onPause() event in all the activities as well as after every startActivity(intentObj) methods.